# How to show that $\left\|F_n^* - F\right\|={{O}_{p}}\left({{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be iid from a cdf $F$ on $R^d$, $X_1^*,\ldots,X_n^*$ iid from empirical cdf $F_n$. Let $F_n^*$ be empirical cdf based on $X_i^*$'s. Using DKW inequality, Let $\rho\left(F_1,F_2\right)=\left\|F_1-F_2\right\|$  How to show that

(a)${{\rho }_{\infty }}\left(F_{n}^{*},F\right)\xrightarrow{a.s}0$

(b)${{\rho }_{\infty }}\left(F_{n}^{*},F\right)={{O}_{p}}\left({{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\right)$

(c)${{\rho }_{L_p}}(F_{n}^{*},F)={{O}_{p}}({{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}})$

My thought is  that

(a)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)>z)& < P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},{{F}_{n}})+{{\rho }_{\infty}}\left({{F}_{n}},F\right)>z) \\ 
 & < \int_{0}^{z}{P({{\rho }_{\infty }}({{F}_{n}},F)>{{z}_{1}})}P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},{{F}_{n}})>z-{{z}_{1}})\mathrm d{{z}_{1}} \quad \text{(Correct?)}\\ 
 & \le \int_{0}^{z}{{{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )nz_{1}^{2}}}{{{{C}'}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )n{{(z-{{z}_{1}})}^{2}}}}d{{z}_{1}}} (DKW)\\ 
 & ={{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{{{C}'}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}\int_{0}^{z}{{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )nz_{1}^{2}}}{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )n{{(z-{{z}_{1}})}^{2}}}}d{{z}_{1}}} \\ 
 & ={{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{{{C}'}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}\int_{0}^{z}{{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )n({{z}^{2}}-2{{z}_{1}}z+2z_{1}^{2})}}d{{z}_{1}}} \\ 
 & ={{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{{{C}'}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{e}^{\frac{-(2-\varepsilon )n{{z}^{2}}}{2}}}\int_{0}^{z}{{{e}^{-(2-\varepsilon )n2{{({{z}_{1}}-\frac{z}{2})}^{2}}}}d{{z}_{1}}\propto {{{{C}''}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{e}^{-{{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}^{\prime \prime \prime }n{{z}^{2}}}}}  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)>z)\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }{{{{{C}''}}_{\varepsilon ,d}}{{e}^{-{{C}_{\varepsilon ,d}}^{\prime \prime \prime }n{{z}^{2}}}}}}<\infty 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    {{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)\xrightarrow{a.s}0
\end{equation}

(b)

From part a $P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)>z)\le C{{e}^{an{{z}^{2}}}}$, where $a,C$ are constant. Let $ C{{e}^{an{{z}^{2}}}}=\epsilon$, then we can derive $z=\sqrt{\frac{\ln \varepsilon -\ln C}{an}}$. So $\exists$ constant ${{D}_{\varepsilon }}=\frac{\sqrt{\ln \varepsilon -\ln C}}{\sqrt{a}}$ s.t. $\forall\epsilon>0$, $P({{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)>\frac{{{D}_{\varepsilon }}}{\sqrt{n}})\le \varepsilon $. In other words, ${{\rho }_{\infty }}(F_{n}^{*},F)={{O}_{p}}({{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}})$.

(c)$$\rho_{L_p}=\|F_n^*-F\|_{L_p}\le\|F_n^*-F_n\|_{L_p}+\|F_n-F\|_{L_p}\le[\|F_n^*-F_n\|_{\infty}\|F_n^*-F_n\|_{L_1}]^{\frac{1}{p}}+[\|F_n-F\|_{\infty}\|F_n-F\|_{L_1}]^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Then I think we can also use DKW inequality, but I don't know how to deal with this $\|\|_{L_1}$, do you have some ideas?

**I also post this question in mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/403434/362220**